# How to convert character to integer in fortran?

Tags: fortran, command-line-arguments

How to manipulate the command line argument?
for example

`te.f90`

```
program print_
integer :: i
character(len = 32) :: arg
i = 1   
Do 
   call get_command_argument(i, arg)
   if ( len_trim(arg) == 0) exit
       write(*,*) trim(arg)
       write(*,*) trim(arg)**2
       i = i + 1
end do
end program print_
```

`te.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( x = 1; x <=3; x++ ))
do
   ./te $x
done
```

I pass `$x` as `arg` which has type `character`, but I want to manipulate `arg` as a number when I execute `./te.sh`, I got the error promotion `Operands of binary numeric operator '**' at (1) are CHARACTER(1)/INTEGER(4)`.

what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert the string (arg) into an integer.

```
program print_
   integer :: i, iarg
   character(len = 32) :: arg
   i = 1   
   Do 
      call get_command_argument(i, arg)
      if ( len_trim(arg) == 0) exit
          write(*,*) trim(arg)
          read(arg,"(I)") iarg
          write(*,*) iarg**2
          i = i + 1
   end do
end program print_
```